How do I fix Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility?
I have recently taken the plunge into using Linux Mint and that means moving my development tasks as well. I am using IntelliJ IDEA and have created a Kotlin Compose Multiplatform project. I have not changed anything and decided to run to make sure everything works.
I get this error message when running:
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
> Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileJava' (23) and 'compileKotlin' (22).


I have also attempted to resolve this by using these JDK's and versions:
openjdk-23 Oracle OpenJDK 23.0.1
corretto-23 Amazon Corretto 23.0.1
corretto-22 Amazon Corretto 22.0.2

As you can probably tell, I don't really have a good understanding of what I am doing so any help would be appreciated.

That question is similar, but this is a genuine duplicate with (my) accepted answer. (Note all the JVMs you are using are version 23 which give the same problem)

If the problem is that you are using Kotlin 2.0.x which cannot compile with JVM 23, you can upgrade to Kotlin 2.1.0 which can.

RE: Comment by @k314159, see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew21.html#kotlin-jvm
